# cakephp form/date helpers

Tags: php, cakephp

I have 3 dropdwons for day month and year. I was combining them till recently to save **date_of_inspection** in the db in mysql format. I was using the Day, month and year cakephp form helpers.This is what i was doing

```
$this->data['Cabinet']['date_of_inspection'] =
    $this->data['Cabinet']['date_of_inspection']['year'].'-'.
    $this->data['Cabinet']['date_of_inspection']['month'].'-'.
    $this->data['Cabinet']['date_of_inspection']['day'];
```

I removed the above line and still the date was being stored in mysql date format. How come ?? Does cakephp do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yes. Date and time "subarrays" are automatically [deconstructed](http://api13.cakephp.org/view_source/model/#l-841) as part of the save process.